# Combining lines not starting with quote using Notepad++ regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a CSV text file that looks like this:

```
"1",
"2",
"3",
Some Text
"4",
"5",
```

What I am trying to do is combine lines that don't begin with a quote. This is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
"1",
"2",
"3", Some Text
"4",
"5",
```

I can successfully find results in the following manner:

```
^[^"]
```

But here is the problem. The result is that the letter "S" gets highlighted and I want to preserve that letter and move it up to the next line. I know that I am going to have to use extended mode after a regex search and replace.

Some things to note is that there are many fields listed above. `It also could be possible that there is no carriage return before "Some Text" appears`. There are also a lot more fields, but I shortened this for simplicity sake.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use this replacement:

```
\r?\n([^"])
```

Or (as `\R` is any linebreak in Notepad++)

```
\R([^"])
```

With

```
 $1
```

The `\r?\n` matches a linebreak, and `([^"])` captures a symbol at the beginning of a line that is not a double quote. We restore it later by getting the captured text with a backreference `$1`.

Settings:

[image]

Comment: Could use `$` rather than `\r?\n` I'd bet

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: No, `$` does not work here. `\R` does and is really better/safer I guess.